# How set a condition in widget?

Tags: flutter

i want to set a condition if (value==7) { Textspan(text: "JACKPOT :"+j.j7)} else { Textspan(text: "JACKPOT :"+j.j14} in this piece of code where there is JACKPOT written, this piece of code is executed in futurebuilder :

```
Container(
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets
                                                        .only(
                                                        bottom: 10),
                                                    child: RichText(
                                                      text: TextSpan(
                                                        children: [
                                                          TextSpan(
                                                              text: "JACKPOT : "  +
                                                                  " ",
                                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                                  fontSize: 20,
                                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight
                                                                      .w800,
                                                                  color: Colors
                                                                      .black)
                                                          ),
                                                          WidgetSpan(
                                                              child: Icon(
                                                                  FontAwesomeIcons
                                                                      .euroSign,
                                                                  color: Colors
                                                                      .amber[900],
                                                                  size: 20)
                                                          ),
```

Comment: You need to add more indentation to your code, so ppl on mobile could care even less your your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ternary operator for this

```
// ......
text: "JACKPOT : "+ value==7 ? j.j7.toString() : j.j14.toString()
// ........
// Given j7 & j14 are int
```

Comment: i do that but doesn't work : TextSpan(text: "JACKPOT : "  + values[index].nb_match==7 ? j.j7 : j.j14+ "  " it says "error: The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [gameapp] lib\grille_lotosport.dart:191)"

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check. Error is due to j7 & j14 being of type int. We need to convert to it to string before concatenation.